# Flume to HBase dependencie failure

Tags: hadoop, hbase, flume-ng

I have installed `HBase` and `Flume` using `Apache Cloudera`. I have a `flume` agent running on a `linux` server, where the `HBase` current master is running.
I'm trying to write from a `spooldir` to `HBase` but I get the following error:

```
...
ERROR org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider: Failed to start agent because dependencies were not found in classpath. Error follows.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/HBaseConfiguration
at  org.apache.flume.sink.hbase.HBaseSink.<init>(HbaseSink.java:116)
...
```

Flume configuration:

```
...
#Sinks
tier1.sinks.hbase-sink.channel          = memory-channel
tier1.sinks.hbase-sink.type             = org.apache.flume.sink.hbase.HBaseSink
tier1.sinks.hbase-sink.table            = FlumeTable
tier1.sinks.hbase-sink.columnFamily     = FlumeColumn
```

I tried to modify the `flume-env.sh` and set `HBASE_HOME` `HADOOP_HOME`, but it changed nothing.

I have succeeded to write to `HDFS`, but the `HBase` is making problems.

Answer (score 2):

I could resolve this problem by adding the path of the hbase-libraries to the FLUME_CLASSPATH in the conf/flume-env.sh, i.e., in my case the file looked like:

```
FLUME_CLASSPATH="/home/USERNAME/hbase-1.0.1.1/lib/*"
```

Hope it helps.