# flum agent with syslogs source and hbase sink

Tags: hadoop, hbase, flume, sink

I try to use flume with syslogs source and hbase sink.
when I run flume agent I get this error : `Failed to start agent because dependencies were not found in classpath. Error follows. java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/HBaseConfiguration`, which means (from that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28600781/flume-to-hbase-dependencie-failure)) that some hbase lib are missing, to solve it I need to set in flume-env.sh file the path to these lib,that what  I did, and  run flume but the error persisted here is the command that I used to run flume agent :  `bin/flume-ng agent --conf ./conf --conf-file ./conf/flume.properties --name agent -Dflume.root.logger=INFO,console`  
 so my question is, If the solution that I used is correct (I need to add lib to flume) why I still get the same error, if not how to solve that problem

**EDIT**
from the doc I read : `The flume-ng executable looks for and sources a file named "flume-env.sh" in the conf directory specified by the --conf/-c commandline option.`.
I haven't test it yet but I think that is the solution (I just need a confirmation )

Comment: one solution would be to copy hbase jars from HBASE_HOME/lib to FLUME_HOME/lib and it works but I want to know how to use flume-env.sh

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to download HBase full tar ball and set the environment variables like HBASE_HOME etc to the right locations. Then Flume can automatically pick the libraries from HBase repo.